# Stoping javascript on page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have this javascript in my code :

```
      function Renew()
      {         
          var txtID = document.getElementById('<%=dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID").ClientID%>');    
          var ID = getCookie('SOIDTextCookie');
          txtID.value = ID;
      }
```

the thing is that on page load it always enters this javascripts and my code breaks because "txtInsertSOID" is named differently in edit and view mode.

what should i do to prevent the programe of running this script on page load? please help

Comment: Please post full code

Comment: If you can't check whether "txtInsertSOID" exists or not, you can use try catch to handle the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindControl` will return `null` if the specified control does not exist. for more info refer [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

```
<%=dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID") != null ? dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID").ClientID : string.Empty %>
```

So change you code as

```
function Renew()
{         
    var txtID = document.getElementById('<%=dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID") != null ? dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID").ClientID : string.Empty %>');   
    if(txtID != null){ 
        var ID = getCookie('SOIDTextCookie');
        txtID.value = ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeMouannes it would be nice if you marked this answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out:-**

```
function Renew() {         
    var txtID = document.getElementById('<%=txtInsertSOID.ClientID%>');    
    var ID = getCookie('SOIDTextCookie');
    txtID.value = ID;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So when do you want to run the script? After the whole body is loaded? In that case you can do on body OnLoad() or even jquery document.ready These will make sure that the whole document is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

In function you can check with control Existence.

So now your updated function

```
    function Renew()
          {         
              if (document.getElementById("txtInsertSOID") != null)
              {
                var txtID = document.getElementById('<%=dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID").ClientID%>');    
                var ID = getCookie('SOIDTextCookie');
                txtID.value = ID;
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that ;)

```
  function Renew()
  {         
    var txtID = document.getElementById('<%=dvSOItem.FindControl("txtInsertSOID").ClientID%>');   
    if(txtID != null){ 
      var ID = getCookie('SOIDTextCookie');
      txtID.value = ID;
    }
  }
```